# NDB query with structured propertiy and projection give unexpected result

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, database-design, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Hi I have these models:

```
class TagProprieta(ndb.Model):
    tag = ndb.StringProperty()
    stato =  ndb.StringProperty()

class RegDevice(ndb.Model):
    comune_key = ndb.KeyProperty()
    reg_id = ndb.StringProperty()
    tags = ndb.StructuredProperty(TagProprieta, repeated=True)
    ....
```

This query returns the expected result (a list with some RegDevice objects):

```
    registration_ids = models.RegDevice.query(\
        models.RegDevice.comune_key==comune_key,\
        models.RegDevice.tags == models.TagProprieta(tag=tag, stato='1')\
        ).fetch()
```

Since I only need the field reg_id, then I changed the last line with this:

```
.fetch(projection=[models.RegDevice.reg_id])
```

The result is an empty list: [ ]

I'd be perfectly fine if i had and **error** due to the limitations of NDB, but It seems to me that and **empty list is not corret**.
Am i doing somethig wrong? Is my only chance to use the former query, and then work on the result in memory? THX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `reg_id` must be indexed for the projection to work.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/projectionqueries#Python_Limitations_on_projections

Try manually setting it in your `index.yaml`

```
- kind: RegDevice
  properties:
  - name: reg_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
registration_ids = models.RegDevice.query(\
    models.RegDevice.comune_key==comune_key,\
    models.RegDevice.tags == models.TagProprieta(tag=tag, stato='1'),\
    projection=[models.RegDevice.reg_id]
    ).fetch()
```

Comment: Tryed, same result as before: [] ,  but THX

Comment: How about `projection=[RegDevice.reg_id]`?

Comment: Or `projection=["reg_id"]`?

Comment: Last suggestion lead to error: global name 'reg_id' is not defined, previous: same error

Comment: and if you use: `.fetch(projection=["reg_id"])` ?

Comment: Are you sure that the entity you fetch HAS a `reg_id`?

Comment: Yes, you can read it in regDevice class and this query works flawlessy:    registration_ids = models.RegDevice.query(models.RegDevice.comune_key==comune_key).fetch(projection=[models.RegDevice.reg_id])

Comment: That's not the same entity as one with `models.RegDevice.tags == models.TagProprieta(tag=tag, stato='1')`

Comment: That's right. But my point is that the query with both the projection and that condition does not work correctly (giving [])  while it gives the correct result with using only one of them.